# Pyspark - Error while loading ML model

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have trained a PySpark ML model with a job submitted using spark-submit. I fail to load this model with another job. I use spark 2.2.0 and python 2.6

My code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("load_model").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

model_path = "/home/lr_model"
lr_model = LinearRegression.load(model_path)
print("Coefficients: " + str(lr_model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(lr_model.intercept))
```

And the unclear error message I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "load_model.py", line 6, in   lr_model = LinearRegression.read().load(model_path)
>     File "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/appcache/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py",
>   line 176, in load   File
>   "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/appcache/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 933, in **call**   File
>   "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/appcache/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco   File
>   "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/appcache/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 312, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o41.load. : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel.(java.lang.String)
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:337)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I think you have to `from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegressionModel` and do `lr_model  = LinearRegressionModel.load(model_path)`

Comment: Additionally Spark 2.2 doesn't support Python 2.6 anymore.